# My screen tears for no reason

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I factory-reset my PC. And ever since then, my game has had issues.

The screen tears horribly while maintaining 144 FPS for my 144Hz monitor (I made sure it was set to that).
Another issue is that there is some sort of input delay, but I play on KBM.

I have uninstalled the drivers for my processor and my graphics card. My PC has a GTX 1060 GPU and it runs completely fine.

Another weird thing is that my game will randomly fix itself. I was able to verify the game one time and it worked normal, but the next day it started off tearing and it is just disappointing. That’s how it works: it fixes itself, then breaks the next day.

If I run in a straight line it looks very smooth, but if I move my cursor it looks horrible. Any tips?

Comment: Have you *re*installed your video card drivers?

Answer (score 3):

Have your tried activating G-sync/V-sync?

V-sync = locking your FPS to your monitor refresh rate, meaning if you have a 60hz monitor, V-sync will cap your FPS at 60.

G-sync = adjusting your monitor's refresh rate to your FPS, meaning if you have a 144hz monitor, you get 89 FPS, G-sync will adjust your monitor's refresh rate to 89.

V-sync is available on most GPUs, G-sync is only available if you have a G-sync monitor, and a GPU that supports it.

If that does not help, try to enable Fast Sync or Adaptive Sync in the Nvidia driver settings, or lock your frame-rate at 140.